# C# list of objects - .Add() by reference .Add() by value

Tags: c#, list

I have an application that queries XML (files) and then stores the values in Lists. I define 2 Classes in identical manners in separate files:

```
namespace Cnc11Info
{
    public class AxisInfo
    {
        public char V300_Label { get; set; }
        public double V300_SlowJog { get; set; }
        public double V300_FastJog { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Cnc11Info
{
    public class DriveInfo
    {
        public static double DriveIndex { get; set; }  
        public static string DriveType { get; set; }
        public static double DriveVersion { get; set; 
    }
}
```

Declare the lists the same:

```
public static List<AxisInfo> axesInfo = new List<AxisInfo>();
public static List<DriveInfo> driveInfo = new List<DriveInfo>();
```

.Add() new item to list the same:

```
MainWindow.axesInfo.Add(new AxisInfo());
MainWindow.driveInfo.Add(new DriveInfo());
```

And insert the data into the properties for each object the same:

```
MainWindow.axesInfo[index].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName.ToString()).SetValue(MainWindow.axesInfo[index], value);

MainWindow.driveInfo[index].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName.ToString()).SetValue(MainWindow.driveInfo[index], value);
```

Where index = 0-7. On each iteration the values are set correctly for each property in the item and, in the case of the List axesInfo each item for axesInfo[i] is set correctly but for driveInfo - Each property is set to the same value for all 8 items in the list. I assume the short answer is all objects in driveInfo are references but why? And how to fix?

[image: structure of axesInfo]

[image: indentical?? structure of driveInfo]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: In the DriverInfo the properties are declared as _static_ so there is only one copy of these properties for every instance declared

Comment: ["While an instance of a class contains a separate copy of all instance fields of the class, **there is only one copy of each static field**."](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords/5248/static#t=201612301947161497946)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DriveInfo` is not `static`, but its properties are. That's the same thing as assigning a single global variable; `public static object` is as close as you get to a `Global` declaration in C#.

Because the properties are static, all instances of `DriveInfo` will have the same value for their properties. You can test this by adding a non-`static` `public` property and setting it with your loop variable `i` as the value (so it counts up as it goes).  You'll see that it changes with each iteration, but that the other values remain the same.

Edit: The overall point is that even if you have 20 objects with the static property MyProp, changing the value of MyProp changes it in every instance of the object.

Comment: Thank you. I must have been staring at the obvious so long I didn't even catch it when I posted my question.